# Combine results of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and I want a consolidated view of two queries in a single one. Below is the table:

```
id   message   wordCount    brand
-----------------------------------
1   xx xx xx     3          Brand1
2   x xx xx x    4          Brand1
3   x x xxxx     3          Brand2
4   x x xx                  Brand2
4   x x          NuLL       Brand1

and so on..
```

I want to write a query that displays the count of non null values i.e.

```
select brand, count(wordCount) wrdCnt
from my_table
where (wordCount is not null and wordCount!='')
group by brand;
```

However, I want a third column also to be displayed that just shows the no. of rows that are there for a brand. This will give me an idea as to for how many rows we did not get the word count

```
select brand, count(*) TotalCnt
from my_table
group by brand;
```

How to get brand, wrdCnt and TotalCnt in a single view?

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: r u sure you want to use COUNT(wordCount) to get the wordCount for a brand? It is just lineCount, not wordCount.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression to do conditional wrdCnt counting:

```
select brand,
       count(*) TotalCnt,
       count(case when wordCount is not null and wordCount!='' then 1 end) as wrdCnt
from my_table
group by brand;
```

Comment: Isn't the is not null unnecessary ?

Comment: @sagi, don't think so, not as it is written here. (As a matter of fact I did just copy-and-paste, to show the procedure.)

Comment: I think when counting null it just won't add up to the number .. like the case expression without an else(will put null when the case is false no?)

Comment: @sagi, I don't know MySQL, can you perhaps simply do `count(wordCount!='')`?

Answer (score -1):

To get the wrdCnt for a brand, you need to use SUM(), not COUNT().

Moreover, you don't do any filter for this, aggregate function only take non-NULL rows and 0 has no effect on SUM().

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    brand,
    SUM(wordCount) wrdCnt,
    COUNT(*) rowCnt
FROM 
    my_table
GROUP BY
    brand;
```

Comment: why the downVote? can I know the reason?